# fop pom and module-info example

Tags: java, apache-fop, java-17, java-platform-module-system

I tried to locate an example of pom.xml and module-info.java to use fop in an embedded way with JPMS, namely Java-17, but could not find one.

E.g. my code:

```
        FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(basePath.toUri()).setPageHeight("297mm")
                .setPageWidth("210mm");
        FopFactory fopFactory = builder.build();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(r));
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        Source src = new StreamSource(fo.toFile());
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(src, res);
```

worked until fop 2.8 with

```
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>batik-script</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        <exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

My module-info.java contains

```
requires Saxon.HE;
requires transitive org.slf4j;
requires java.prefs;
requires fop;
requires xmlgraphics.commons;
requires java.xml;
```

When upgrading to fop version 2.9 it misses the package `org.apache.fop.apps.` in compilation.

As I found that solution by trial-and-error, my question is a bit broader: **How to embed fop in a JPMS project environment?**

Comment: "Does not work". How do you know? An error message? Could you please [edit] that detail into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly the classes(`org.apache.fop.apps.*`) you are looking for have been abstracted to `fop-core`, hence adding a `requires` directive for that as a module with version `2.9` shall get you going.

```
requires fop.core;
```

---

In fact referenced in a few documents and the mailing list threads --

> The `fop` jar packages `fop-util`, `fop-events`, and `fop-core`, so you want
> either the all-in-one jar, or the other 3 jars, but not both.

So, it would be better to replace the **`requires fop`** with

```
requires fop.core;
requires fop.events;
requires fop.util;
```

**But**, the contributors needs to focus further to restructure the common packages to make all these three being used independently and combined by clients or else as shared by you compilation fails with :

```
java: the unnamed module reads package org.apache.fop.events from both fop.core and fop.events
```

Comment: In pom.xml I have replace fop by fop-core, fop-events, and fop-util. Also in module-info.java as you've descibed. It leads the these errors:

https://paste.debian.net/1292129/

Comment: @ngong Got it. There is still work to do, in order to ensure that the same packages are not exported from both modules. But since these are mostly automatic modules for now, that might be a plan for the future. In your case(code shared in question), at present `fop.core` might be sufficient, if you were to use modules with the updated version. But to make use of all of these, folks contributing to `fop` would have to ensure renaming packages or restructuring further.

Comment: I changed module-info.java as you have described, also in pom.xml I substitured fop by fop-core, fop-events, and fop-util. This resultes in [theses errors](https://paste.debian.net/1292285/) from m2e console, or in long using [mvn -e test](https://paste.debian.net/1292286/).

Comment: reduce module-info.java to fop-core without fop-events and using fop [in this way](https://paste.debian.net/1292288/) leads to *FAILED: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fop/events/EventBroadcaster*
Hence, I should stick to 2.8, waiting for 2.10?